# How to access an Array Controller from App Delegate?

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I have a simple Core Data based Cocoa app that uses an ArrayController to display model objects (employees). Two buttons allow for adding and deleting employees. The add button is wired with bindings to the insert: action of the Array Controller however the delete button is wired to a confirmDelete method in the App Delegate, which shows a modal confirmation dialog.

How do I get access in the confirmDelete method of the App Delegate to the Array Controller to remove the selected object from the Array Controller (and the underlying store)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do like this-

1. Bind array controller to app delegate
2. In confirmDelete method, add this line after checking your conditions : [yourArrayController remove:nil];

Hope this helps :)

---- Edit ----

Please be sure to save the context after performing deletion, otherwise it will not be reflected in persistent store.

ie. after this line:

```
[yourArrayController remove:nil];
```

Add this line:

```
NSError *error = nil;
if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
   NSLog(@"Some Useful Message!");
}
```

Generally, this code is used in - applicationShouldTerminate: , which automatically saves it to persistent store, when application quits.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm a bit confused. The Array Controller is already bound to the App Delegate, under the "Parameters" section of the Array Controller bindings. This is to allow the Array Controller access to the managedObjectContext in the App Delegate. Should I add another binding? If so, which one as there are several options (ahum, you might have guessed I'm an absolute beginner with OS X app development). Thanks again...

Comment: I was a bit too excited. Although the deleted object disappears from the list when confirming the delete, it will still be there after restarting the app so apparently it has not been deleted from the data store. Anybody any ideas on this? Many thanks!

Comment: @Roger if this hasn't answered your question then you should update your question explaining why and uncheck this answer.

Comment: @Roger.. I have edited my answer, please check it. Also please consider suggestion by Peter Hosey.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your application's delegate showing such a dialog, anyway? That's not a responsibility of the application's delegate.

I suggest moving that, and anything else that isn't part of that object being the application's delegate, to another object. In my applications, that's usually the object that owns the window, the array controller, and anything else in that nib, and *is owned* (created in `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` and released in `applicationWillTerminate:`) *by* the application's delegate.

Cleaning up your object graph is almost always the solution to any “how do I get to object A from object B?” question.